# Unplugging ethernet cable without disabling NIC

Tags: ip, ethernet, network-adapter

Is it possible to configure the OS (Windows XP or Linux) or the NIC itself so that the NIC/interface remains enabled when the ethernet cable is unplugged?

Often, especially when I'm tinkering, it's really annoying to have all my open TCP connections drop out just because I have unplugged the cable.

Comment: At least in XP, unplugging your NIC should set its state to "disconnected" not "disabled".

Comment: XP is horribly broken in this regard. This is one of Microsoft's most foolish design decisions. One of the primary design goals of the TCP protocol is that temporary interruptions in network connectivity don't break connections. (You shouldn't have to do anything in Linux. The connections shouldn't break.)

Comment: Whatever its state, I would like it to have no effect on open TCP connections that are not currently sending data.

Answer (score 2):

I can think of two ways which may solve your issue.

One way is to make use of a small / cheap network switch or hub, which sits between your computer and your "upstream" router or switch.  That way, if you need to disconnect or unpower that switch, the computer won't (can't) notice the link state change, because it's connected to its own hub.  This does have the disadvantage of being clumsy, requiring a separate device, its power supply, and at least one extra wire.

Another way which might work, is to configure the windows TCP/IP stack to ignore the ethernet *media sense*.  You can do this by changing a registry setting ...  under the key `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\System\CurrentControlSet\Services\Tcpip\Parameters` , change or set the `DisableDHCPMediaSense` value to 1 (REG_DWORD).  See [How to disable the Media Sensing feature for TCP/IP in Windows](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/239924) .  This is supposed to prevent the TCP/IP stack from unbinding from the adapter when it goes to disconnected state, which ideally will keep existing TCP connections from being dropped due to a transient disconnect.